# How can I limit a string to no more than a certain length?

Tags: c#

I tried the following:

```
var Title = LongTitle.Substring(0,20)
```

This works but not if LongTitle has a length of less than 20.  How can I limit strings to a maximum of 20 characters but not get an error if they are just for example 5 characters long?

Comment: Check the length of the string, and if it's greater than 20 characters truncate, otherwise leave it as is.

Answer (score 44):

Make sure that length won't exceed `LongTitle` (`null` checking skipped):

```
int maxLength = Math.Min(LongTitle.Length, 20);
string title = LongTitle.Substring(0, maxLength);
```

This can be turned into extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Truncates string so that it is no longer than the specified number of characters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">String to truncate.</param>
    /// <param name="length">Maximum string length.</param>
    /// <returns>Original string or a truncated one if the original was too long.</returns>
    public static string Truncate(this string str, int length)
    {
        if(length < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length), "Length must be >= 0");
        }

        if (str == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int maxLength = Math.Min(str.Length, length);
        return str.Substring(0, maxLength);
    }
}
```

Which can be used as:

```
string title = LongTitle.Truncate(20);
```

Comment: Maybe also checking for `null` in the extension method?

Comment: I too have used an extension method for this, but out of respect for others who maintain my code (and for the sake of brevity), might I suggest a more apt method signature: Truncate(int maxLength)

Comment: @Chris Yes, this is indeed much better name for this method :) Thank you

Comment: length also could be optional parameter.

Comment: @adt You're free to do whatever you like with this method. `length` could be optional, but what value would it take? `0`? Does it even makes sanse to truncate string to empty string?

Answer (score 19):

Shortest, the:

```
var title = longTitle.Substring(0, Math.Min(20, longTitle.Length))
```

---

#### Update

Ok since some new C# version this suggested variant became the shortest:

```
var title = longTitle[..Math.Min(20, longTitle.Length)]
```

Comment: Shorter: var Title = longTitle[..Math.Min(20, longTitle.Length)]

Answer (score 9):

```
string title = new string(LongTitle.Take(20).ToArray());
```

Comment: Note this is quite inefficient since it create an intermediate char array which is then immediately copied and discarded.

Comment: @Lee: You are right, but with small string, it's trivial

Answer (score 5):

If the string Length is bigger than 20, use 20, else use the Length.

```
string  title = LongTitle.Substring(0,
    (LongTitle.Length > 20 ? 20 : LongTitle.Length));
```

Comment: Learn to use Math.Min for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the StringLength attribute. That way no string can be stored that is longer (or shorter) than a specified length.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
[StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Your Message")]
public string LongTitle;
```